# How to make an MSDOS folder hidden in Linux

Tags: linux, attributes, hidden, dos, flags

Could anyone tell me how to make an MSDOS folder hidden in Linux. I normally use mattrib to change MSDOS file attribute flags but apparently it doesn't work with folders. Shortly, I am looking for suitable "mattrib +h" call to make a folder hidden.

Thanks.

Comment: In linux any file/folder starting with `.` will not be listed by normal `ls` command. But `ls -a` will list it.

Comment: Yes I know this. However I am zipping the files that I get from Windows. So I should keep the names as they are I guess. If I put . at the beginning of the folder name, zip file will also contain the folder with . Considering that I unzip this file later on Windows environment, I guess having different file name (with dot) will cause some problems. Is there any other way without adding dot?

Comment: Nope, I guess. Check http://superuser.com/questions/359784/hide-files-in-linux-without-using-the-dot

Comment: Otherwise, before zipping it you can run a script to remove that dot by renaming them

Comment: I am currently trying to make it hidden before zipping. I hope that zipping process won't change any attribute.

Comment: Am afraid the file may not have hidden attributes set when moved to windows. Please cross check.